# Language invariant Double.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am passing a double across a network, 
currently I do

```
double value = 0.25;
string networkMsg = "command " + value;
```

the `networkMsg` is fine in english where its 0.25 and french where its 0,25, but when i go from a french computer to an english computer one side is making it 0.25 and the other is trying to read 0,25.

So i can to use region invariant methods in my code.

I have found Val(`networkMsg`) that will always read 0.25 no matter the region.

but I cannot find a guaranteed way of converting from value to 0.25 region invariant.
would `value.toString("0.0")` work?

Comment: Use this overload: [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx) and call it like `0.25.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: why can't you transfer it as binary using [BitConverter.GetBytes Method (Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5be4sc9.aspx)

Comment: @bansi that would presume that the network protocol is readily changed. If it is a text-based protocol that won't work well.

Comment: @MarcGravell it was just a suggestion if it is not difficult to change protocol (if already implemented) or if creating protocol.

Comment: @bansi indeed, I'm a big fan of binary protocols - I don't disagree that it would be a better option: it would also be more reliable (no rounding errors) and often more compact (4 or 8 bytes, regardless of value). I don't disagree in principle.

Comment: I created [some extension methods](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/6fe3298b8ac6d9d0d9872dd811a63908) to get an invariant string for all these types. That was quite a research.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
string networkMsg = "command " + value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or:

```
string networkMsg = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "command {0}", value);
```

This needs `using System.Globalization;` in the top of your file.

Note: If you need full precision, so that you can restore the exact double again, use the `Format` solution with [the roundtrip format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-round-trip-r-format-specifier) `{0:R}`,  instead of just `{0}`. You can use other format strings, for example `{0:N4}` will insert thousands separators and round to four dicimals (four digits after the decimal point).

---

Since C# 6.0 (2015), you can now use:

```
string networkMsg = FormattableString.Invariant($"command {value}");
```

Comment: Be careful: the documentation says that the roundtrip format `R` if not the best to get an invariant value. They recommend format `G17` for doubles and `G9` for floats.

Comment: @SandRock Also, in the (old) .NET Framework 4.8 an old `.ToString` is still used, while in .NET Core ([since .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/)) and its descendant .NET, a more IEEE compliant formatting is used. Exactly what `"R"` does depends on that!

Answer (score 14):

The `.` in the format specifier `"0.0"` doesn't actually mean "dot" - it means "decimal separator" - which is `,` in France and several other European cultures. You probably want:

```
value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or

```
value.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

For info, you can see this (and many other things) by inspecting the *fr* culture:

```
var decimalSeparator = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr")
            .NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
```

Comment: what decimal seperator and the rest does invariant culture use?

Comment: @f1wade The invariant culture is based on the English language and uses `"."` as decimal separator, and `","` as so-called group separator.

Answer (score 4):

Specify the invariant culture as the format provider:

```
value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```